# Join same table and columns twice

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've made 2 tables. One with assigned users to works (called employers):

[image: table shops_employers]

...and the second with users:

[image: table users]

I want to get user name and surname from **users** by appealing to column **se_u_id** in **shops_employers**, and again name and surname by appealing to column **se_so_add_u_id** in **shops_employers**. Here is code that I wrote:

```
$this->db->from('shops_employers as se');
$this->db->where('se_s_id', $shopID);
$this->db->where('se_accepted', 1);
$this->db->where('se_active', 1);
$this->db->join('users as u', 'se.se_u_id = u.u_id');
return $this->db->get()->result();
```

But I don't have any idea what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$this->db->from('shops_employers se');
$this->db->where('se.se_s_id', $shopID);
$this->db->where('se.se_accepted', 1);
$this->db->where('se.se_active', 1);
$this->db->join('users u', 'se.se_u_id = u.u_id', 'left');
return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: It's not working, it's shows the same name and surname for se_u_id and se_so_add_u_id.